# Why the prep 'in' used in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, prepositions

> In Golden State, Cousins will team with four fellow All-Stars in the starting lineup **in** Stephen Curry, Klay Thompson, Kevin Durant and Draymond Green.

I saw the sentence from [this article](https://www.yahoo.com/sports/sources-demarcus-cousins-agrees-deal-warriors-003552151.html). The part that really confuses me is "***in*** Stephen Curry, Klay Thompson, Kevin Durant and Draymond Green". I would use **namely** to provide a list, if I wrote it.

> In Golden State, Cousins will team with four fellow All-Stars in the starting lineup, **namely**, Stephen Curry, Klay Thompson, Kevin Durant and Draymond Green.

What's the usage of "**in**" here?

Comment: @Em. What does it mean "you've got a friend in me"?

Comment: It roughly means "I am your friend".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an extension of the preposition's physical sense of *containment*. The preposition **in** in this context refers to  *embodiment* of a quality.

> You have a friend in me.
>
> In Golden State, Cousins will team with four fellow All-Stars in the
>   starting lineup in Stephen Curry, Klay Thompson, Kevin Durant and
>   Draymond Green.

What quality is being embodied there? "All-Stars".

{friend} in {me}

{All-Stars} in {Curry, Thompson, Durant, and Green}.

Comment: That makes much more sense. Is this usage of 'in' common? Regional or dialectal?

Comment: It is not regional or dialectal,  nor is it rare.

Comment: See those examples here where the object of **in** is a proper name or an entity of some kind: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22had%20an%20ally%20in%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en

Answer (score 0):

This particular use of **in** is strange.

Although **in** can be used in other contexts, you can't have a starting lineup **in** somebody. (Only people **in** a starting lineup.)

Instead, you could have a starting lineup that **consists of** some people.

But a simpler way of expressing this is:

> In Golden State, Cousins will team with four fellow All-Stars, Stephen Curry, Klay Thompson, Kevin Durant and Draymond Green, in the starting lineup.

Your own rephrasing works as well.

Comment: I disagree. You can have a starting line up in _A, B, C..._, but I couldn't find/choose a dictionary entry to support me. Maybe it's a regional difference.